# Export a value from an API call in a Trailing Closure SwiftUI

Tags: swift, api, swiftui

When working with API, on this code base:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in 
       guard case .success (let response) = result else{return}
       responseText = (response.first?.choice.first?.text ?? "")
}
```

How can I export `responseText` outside the API call?

I’m relatively new to SwiftUI I've been trying to bind `responseText` to a variable outside the body without success.

Comment: How/where did you declare responseText?

Comment: ```responseText``` on the example code above was declared outside the ```var body: some View{```. On the how it was ```var responseText: String``` @Asperi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in view, then it could be

```
@State private var responseText = ""  // or optional if needed

// ...

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in 
       guard case .success (let response) = result else{return}

       DispatchQueue.main.async { // update on UI queue
         self.responseText = (response.first?.choice.first?.text ?? "")
       }
}
```